# Cannot find a function declared inside a for each loop

Tags: r, trading

I am coding a Rscript for carrying out Jtst for pair trading.I declared a function to find out the correlation between two single stocks in the first place, then I add a for each loop to do the task for a list of stocks.However the for each loop did not recognize the first function.

I have tried to use doSHOW function as suggested by information on the Internet, but it did not work.

```
pkgs <- list("quantmod", "doParallel", "foreach", "urca")
lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = T)
registerDoParallel(cores = 4)

jtest <- function(t1, t2) {
  start <- sd
  getSymbols(t1, from = start)
  getSymbols(t2, from = start)
  j <- summary(ca.jo(cbind(get(t1)[, 6], get(t2)[, 6])))
  r <- data.frame(stock1 = t1, stock2 = t2, stat = j@teststat[2])
  r[, c("pct10", "pct5", "pct1")] <- j@cval[2, ]
  return(r)
}

pair <- function(lst) {
  d2 <- data.frame(t(combn(lst, 2)))
  stat <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(d2), .combine = rbind) %dopar% jtest(as.character(d2[i, 1]), as.character(d2[i, 2]))
  stat <- stat[order(-stat$stat), ]
  rownames(stat) <- NULL
  return(stat)
}

sd <- "2018-01-01"
tickers <- c("FITB", "BBT", "MTB", "STI", "PNC", "HBAN", "CMA", "USB", "KEY", "JPM", "C", "BAC", "WFC")
pair(tickers)
```

Error in jtest(as.character(d2[i, 1]), as.character(d2[i, 2])) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "jtest""

Comment: `.export = "jtest"`

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: @Roland when I just add . export = "jtest" within the for each function {stat <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(d2), .combine = rbind,.export = "jtest") %dopar% jtest(as.character(d2[i, 1]), as.character(d2[i, 2])) }  , another error happens: Error in jtest(as.character(d2[i, 1]), as.character(d2[i, 2])) : task 1 failed - "could not find function "getSymbols""

Comment: Please read the foreach documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/foreach/versions/1.4.4/topics/foreach You need to load the packages on the workers.

Comment: And you will need to export your variables ```sd``` and ```tickers``` along with what Roland has already pointed out.  You have to explicitly provide all the information to each core for the task to be executed (global variables, packages, functions, etc.).

Comment: can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I specified the necessary function in the foreach call. The function supposed to generate lags of the time series variable.

This version does not work:

```
 Ylag = foreach(i = 1:maxlagsY,.combine = 'cbind') %dopar%{mylag(Y,k = i)}
```

While this one does:

```
Ylag = foreach(i = 1:maxlagsY,.export = "mylag",.combine = 'cbind') %dopar%{mylag(Y,k = i)}
```

So, the answer is in specifying the user-defined functions in the foreach call.